# Find missing lines in csv using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, csv, cron

I get an csv file every day and would like to compare with the file from the day before. New lines are added, several changes are made in existing lines and some lines are removed.

I could handle all changes of the file except the losing lines.
How could i get the missing lines using a shell script in a cron job?

I would like to put the missing Lines in a third csv file to handle them seperatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man diff`

Using diff, you can get the changes between two files.
Then depending on how you want to handle them, just `grep` the output of `diff` to get what you want.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer is OK for you, feel free to "accept" it (the green tick on the left).

Comment: Is there a way to specifically get removed lines via diff?

Comment: Depends if you consider changed lines as removed lines followed by an inserted line. If so, `diff a.csv b.csv | grep '^<'` will do it.

Comment: Otherwise, not sure how to handle it :-)

Comment: Thank you ... I have tried to do this. Using diff a.csv b.csv | grep '^<' give me changed and removed lines...so new added lines are sortet out. So i only need to additionally sort out changed lines to have only the removed lines left. Could you give me another hint to to this?

Comment: `diff a.csv b.csv | grep -E -A1 '^[0-9]+d[0-9]+$' | grep -v '^--$' | sed -n '0~2 p' | sed -re 's,^< (.*)$,\1,g'` . It does the diff, the get the deleted lines using `grep`, adding one line of context after (the actual deleted line). Then it removes '--' lines inserted as contiguous delimiters by grep. Then it takes one line every two lines (`0~2`) using `sed`, and finally it displays the line by removing the `< ` header using `sed` again.