# Find multible missing lines in csv using diff

Tags: shell, unix, csv, grep, diff

One part of my problem was solved with this answer:
[Threadlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358745/find-missing-lines-in-csv-using-shell-script)
, but an important part of my problem was unsolved!

After using

```
diff a.csv b.csv | grep -E -A1 '^[0-9]+d[0-9]+$' | grep -v '^--$' | sed -n '0~2 p' | sed -re 's,^< (.*)$,\1,g'
```

several times i found something left.
Sometimes multible following lines are deleted.
If only one line was deleted there are something like this found:

`3663d3661`

For multible lines it is:

`3724,3725d3718`

So i changed the `diff` call to:

```
diff a.csv b.csv | grep -E -A1 '^[0-9]+\,*[0-9]*d[0-9]+$' | grep -v '^--$' | sed -n '0~2 p' | sed -re 's,^< (.*)$,\1,g'
```

This works for the first of multiple deleted lines.

My question is:
How could i get all deletet lines (maybe 5 following lines) in such a case?
What did i have to change in the `diff` call?

Comment: Could you attach any diff output example and expected final result?

Comment: Sure...example diff result:

`6715c6643
< Frau;;;Blub1;;Blob;19860314;Blub1.Blob@uni.de;
---
> Frau;;;Blub2;;Blob;19860314;Blub2.Blob@uni.de;
6745d6672
< Frau;;;Blub3;;Blooob;19911002;Blub3.Blooob@uni.de;
6842d6844,6772
< Herr;Dipl.Ing;;Ping;;Pong;19860225;Ping.Pong@uni.de;
< Herr;Dipl.Ing;;Ping2;;Pong;19931002;Ping2.Pong@uni.de;
< Herr;Dipl.Ing;;Ping3;;Pong;19871212;Ping3.Pong@uni.de;
6851c6781
< Herr;Dr.rer.nat.;;Ying;;Yang;19460610;YING.YANG@uni.de;
---
> Herr;Dr.rer.nat.;;Ying;;Yang;19460610;ying.yang@uni.de;`

Comment: what i actual get: `Frau;;;Blub3;;Blooob;19911002;Blub3.Blooob@uni.de;
Herr;Dipl.Ing;;Ping;;Pong;19860225;Ping.Pong@uni.de;`

Comment: what i want to get: `Frau;;;Blub3;;Blooob;19911002;Blub3.Blooob@uni.de;
Herr;Dipl.Ing;;Ping;;Pong;19860225;Ping.Pong@uni.de;
Herr;Dipl.Ing;;Ping2;;Pong;19931002;Ping2.Pong@uni.de;
Herr;Dipl.Ing;;Ping3;;Pong;19871212;Ping3.Pong@uni.de;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
diff a.csv b.csv | sed -n '/^[0-9]\+d[0-9]*/,/^[0-9]\+[^d]*$/{/^[0-9]\+/d;s/^< //;p}'
```

will do that.

```
/^[0-9]\+d[0-9]*/,/^[0-9]\+[^d]*$/
```

will find the string range which are deleted

```
/^[0-9]\+/d
```

will delete all `6842d6844,6772`

```
s/^< //
```

will replace all `<` in the beginning of lines

and `p` will print the line.